# how to resolver 502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, iis, plesk, windows-server-2019

I am getting the following error after publsishing my web application.

502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.
There is a problem with the page you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server (while acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server, it received an invalid response from the content server.

Before the project was working fine on live one but when I have published this version of the project I am getting this error in uploading the image. Project is also working fine on local server.
Uploading image is also working fine when i first time upload the image but after i want to edit the image i am getting this error.I have done the follwong code for uploading the image

```
 if (picture?.Length > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = Common.GetUniqueName(picture.FileName, _env);
                    Common.FileResponse response = Common.SaveImageFile(picture, _env, fileName);
                    if (response.Equals(Common.FileResponse.Ok))
                    {
                        article.Picture = fileName;
                        if (article.Id>0)
                        {
                            var oldFileName = _context.userCvs.Where(x => x.Id == article.Id).Select(x => x.Picture).FirstOrDefault();
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(oldFileName))
                            {
                                Common.RemoveUploadedFiles(oldFileName, _env);
                            }
    
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("Picture", response.ToString());
                    }
                }
```

The following function for saving uploaded file

```
public static FileResponse SaveUploadedFile(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile file, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment env, string uploadedFileName = "", bool isCvs = false, bool isContent = false, bool IsProfile=false)
        {
            if (file == null || file.Length <= 0) return FileResponse.Nothing;
            // limit 5mb file size 5242880
            if (file.Length > 124288000) return FileResponse.ExceedFileSize;

            if (!IsAllowedExt(Path.GetExtension(file.FileName)))
            {
                return FileResponse.ExtNotAllowed;
            }


            var fileName = uploadedFileName == "" ? file.FileName : uploadedFileName;
            var directory = Path.Combine( env.WebRootPath, isCvs ? UploadCvsDirectory : isContent? UploadContentDirectory :IsProfile ? UploadprofileDirectory: UploadDirectory);

            if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(directory, fileName)))
            {
                return FileResponse.FileExists;
            }
          

            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(directory, fileName), FileMode.Create))
                {
                   file.CopyTo(fileStream);
                }
          

           
            return FileResponse.Ok;
        }
```

THe  following function for removing upload file

```
public static void RemoveUploadedFiles(string fileName, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment env, bool isCvs = false, bool isContent = false)
      
        if (fileName == null) return;
                    try
                    {
                        var directory = Path.Combine(env.WebRootPath, isCvs ? UploadCvsDirectory : isContent ? UploadContentDirectory : UploadDirectory);
                        if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(directory, fileName)))
                        {
                            File.Delete(Path.Combine(directory, fileName));
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
        
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Hi @Shahab Ghouri, where did you host this application?

Comment: Hi @Rena I have hosted this on Ovh VPS. I have installed windows server 2019 there and plesk panel also to manage my web applications